# Are there java bindings for OpenGL ES 2.0 on the Android platform?

Tags: android, jogl, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.1

I know that the recently released android ndk r3 supports opengl es 2.0 on supported phones (nexus one for example), however it doesn't say whether there are java bindings for opengl es 2.0 included in the SDK yet. Are said bindings on the way, and if not, does JOGL2 support the opengl es 2.0 profile on the android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Someone wrote some bindings here:
http://apistudios.com/hosted/marzec/badlogic/wordpress/?p=343

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the Android 2.2 SDK includes ES 2.0 java bindings.